# Font resizer with jquery and css

Tags: jquery, html, css, fonts

I am working on website, that has font-size property given to its body. (Thus all elements on the page inherits that)

1. Some tags on the page are given font-size in % percentage.
2. some tags are given property in pixels (px).

I am trying to write a font resizer that works way

```
$('.internal-article *').each(function( index ) {
 var FontSize = $(this).css("fontSize");
 var FontSize = parseFloat(FontSize, 10);
 FontSize = FontSize+1;
 $(this).css("font-size",FontSize+"px");
});
```

This does not works for the pages where the website has property in pixels as it refers to the parent element font and its already increased in the process of traversing each font.

Please suggest inputs

Answer (score 0):

try to chage this:

```
var FontSize = $(this).css("fontSize");
```

to this:

```
var FontSize = $(this).css("font-size");
```

for me works fine:
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hCX56/)